# Trying to create tables with Oracle for an assignment but I can't see the issues with the syntax. Any help is much appreciated

Tags: oracle

This is the code:

```
create table instructor (
       id varchar(10) primary key,
       name varchar(15) not null,
       dept_name varchar(20) not null
            references department(dept_name) on delete cascade,
       salary varchar(20) not null
);

create table teaches (
       id varchar(10) primary key
            references instructor(id) on delete cascade,
       course_id varchar(15) not null check
            references section(course_id),
       sec_id varchar(5) not null
            references section(sec_id),
       semester varchar(15)
            references section(semester),
       year int not null
            references section(year)
);

create table student (
       id varchar(10) not null,
       name varchar(20) not null,
       dept_name varchar(15) not null
            references department(dept_id) on delete cascade,
       tot_cred int not null
);

create table advisor (
       s_id  varchar(10) primary key
            references student(id) on delete cascade,
       i_id varchar(6)
            references instructor(id) on delete cascade
);

create table department (
       dept_name varchar(15) primary key,
       building varchar(10),
       budget int
);

create table course (
       course_id varchar(10) primary key,
       title varchar(10),
       dept_name varchar(15)
            references department(dept_name) on delete cascade,
       credits int
);

create table prereq (
        course_id varchar(10) 
            references course(course_id) on delete cascade,
        prereq_id varchar(10) 
            references course(course_id) on delete cascade,
        primary key (course_id, prereq_id)
);

create table takes (
        id varchar(10) not null
            references student(id) on delete cascade,
        course_id varchar(10) not null
            references section(course_id) on delete cascade,
        sec_id varchar(10) not null
            references section(sec_id) on delete cascade,
        semester varchar(10) not null
            references section(semester) on delete cascade,
        year int not null
            references section(year) on delete cascade,
        grade varchar(10) not null
        primary key (id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
);

create table section (
        course_id varchar(10) not null
                references course(course_id),
        sec_id varchar(10) not null, 
        semester varchar(10) not null,
        year varchar(10) not null,
        building varchar(10) not null
            references classroom(building),
        room_no varchar(5) not null
            references classroom(room_no),
        time_slot_id varchar(5) not null
            references time_slot(time_slot_id),
        primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
);

create table classroom (
        building varchar(10) not null,
        room_no varchar(5) not null,
        capacity varchar(10) not null,
        primary key (building, room_no)
);

create table time_slot (
        time_slot_id varchar(5) not null
            references section(time_slot_id),
        day varchar(10) not null,
        start_time varchar(10) not null,
        end_time varchar(10) not null,
        primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_time)
);
```

This is the output:

Table created.

ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

ORA-00904: "DEPT_ID": invalid identifier

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Table created.

Table created.

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: This is the database layout - https://imgur.com/gallery/wRkArmQ

Comment: You can't reference `department` in your `instructor` table because you haven't created `department` yet. Reorder your `create table` commands to account for dependencies.

Comment: you are referring to tables before they are created. Sort the table create instructions so that the tables with references are only created after the dependent upon ones.
The alternative is to remove the references from the table creation instruction and do that on a later stage via ALTER TABLE (I personally avoid this approach whenever possible but sometime it is the only option).

Comment: As noted, your errors are due to the order of table creation. But let me point out some other 'coding standard' issues.  1) In oracle, use VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR, which is only supported for backward compatibility. 2) Make column names descriptive, like 'department_name', not like 'name'. 3) Use proper data types. 'salary' should be NUMBER, not VARCHAR.  (I've only given one example of each point, you need to go through the entire set of tables with an eye toward these points.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I am almost finished fixing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `student`, the foreign key should reference `department.dept_name` and not `department.dept_id`.
- In `student` there is no primary key, so all the other tables that reference `student` will fail.
- In `time_slot`, you have a referential constraint that references `section` which, in turn, references back to the same column in `time_slot` so you have circular constraints; you probably want to remove the `foreign key` constraint from `time_slot`.
- In `time_slot`, you probably want the `primary key` on just `time_slot_id` and a composite `unique` constraint on `time_slot_id`, `day`, and `start_time`.
- **NEVER** store days and times as strings; always use a `DATE` data type (which, in Oracle, can store both date and time). If, in `time_slot` you are storing a date and time then just use two `DATE` columns for `start_time` and `end_time`. If you are storing day-of-week and time-of-day then you could use a `NUMBER(1,0)` for day-of-week and `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)` for start and end times (or don't use a day column and just use two `INTERVAL DAY(1) TO SECOND (0)` data types for start and end time and measure from the start of the week).
- In `section` you reference `classroom.building` and `classroom.room` individually; however, that is a composite primary key and should be a single referential constraint.
- In `teaches` there is a random `check` keyword that should be removed.
- In `teaches` and `takes`, `course_id`, `sec_id`, `semester` and `year` are a composite key that need to be referenced together.
- Data types are optional when you have a column that is part of a referential constraint. If you remove the data type then it will use the parent table's data type and will ensure consistency between tables.
- You need to re-order the tables so that primary keys are created before the foreign keys that reference them.
- `salary`, `capacity` and `year` should be numeric data types.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2ea4d57071dcd135d10e2be3fefc6f7a)*

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all of these helpful tips! I will try all of these now